# How to copy a large dataframe to a smaller one?

Tags: python, pandas

Probably have been asked before but I could not find anything. Learning Pandas and I thought the learning curve would not be so steep - I was wrong =)
I am importing a csv file with over 20 million rows. Problem is that it is making it hard to work with because of the size.
Just altering a column to use proper dateTime takes ages.

So my first idea was to tail the last 100 rows -

```
shortDataFrame = longDataFrame.tail(100).copy()
```

However this gives me some strange KeyError: 0L when I try to check the type for certain columns.
This gives errors-

```
type(shortDataFrame['Time'][0])
```

This works and gives no errors on original long dataFrame

```
type(longDataFrame['Time][0])
```

So how to make a large dataframe into a smaller one to make it more manageable?

Comment: do it the right way: `shortDataFrame['Time'].dtype`

Comment: the size of data is relative to the machine you are working on. In your case, your approach is right, just take a sample to try whatever code you want, and later run it on all if needed.

Comment: It returns an object. How do I know if Time column holds correct format of date and it is not a string?

Comment: Oddly now it shows correct value for the time column which are dates.... dtype('<M8[ns]')
Why is using type wrong and not dtype?

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you a random sample of the original dataframe with only 100 rows:

```
shortDataFrame = longDataFrame.sample(100)
```

The sample will have exactly the same columns as the "mother" dataframe.

Comment: Do you know the difference of using shortDataFrame = longDataFrame.tail(100).copy()
vs. shortDataFrame = longDataFrame.sample(100)

Comment: `tail` is surely not a random sample. Also, there is no need to copy unless you plan to modify the sample but do not want to modify the original dataframe.

Comment: Just compared the two and .sample() scrambled the order of rows. I am planning just what you said- altering the short version and leaving the long original intact.

Comment: The row order in pandas is not important because each row has an index and the indexes are preserved.